# How to use iphone internet tethering via USB with Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, usb, iphone, connection-sharing

What are the steps to use iPhone 3G internet tethering via USB on Ubuntu 10.04? Is there software I need to install on Ubuntu for this? The tethering works fine on Windows.

Comment: How about tethering via Bluetooth? Would that be fine?

Comment: The bluetooth is not working properly in iphone, it is not detecting any device, its a bug in iphone.

Comment: You need to jailbreak your iPhone first. This will void your warranty.

Comment: don't worry, i did that already before 6 months :)

Comment: @iamsid this is incorrect, you don't have to jailbreak your phone, theres a kernel driver for this!

Comment: @echox: +1. Yes, this is wrong. :) Jeez, my bad, I just found out about `libimobiledevice` and the iPhone Ethernet driver for Linux. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this how-to: [Getting iPhone Internet Tethering Working in Linux](http://techie-buzz.com/foss/getting-iphone-internet-tethering-working-in-linux.html) (No jailbreaking involved!)

Answer (score 2):

Diego Diagio created an iPhone kernel module called "ipheth".

It will be available in the kernel with version 2.6.34.

This module will register your phone as a network interface and you can simply use it with your dhcp-client or network manager.

Set up the Ubuntu Repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the Kernel Module:

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs ipheth-utils
```

After that, enable tethering on your phone and connect it with your computer. Use `dmesg` to check if the device was recognized. Usually you will now have a new networking device, like `/dev/ethX`. Use it in your network manager or use dhclient, for example:

```
dhclient eth2
```

In addtion: My android phone registres as usb0, so it is `dhclient usb0` to do the trick.

If you problems getting the repository to work, see the [project page](http://giagio.com/wiki/moin.cgi/iPhoneEthernetDriver) for further information.

**Advantage: No jailbreaking and additional port binding / proxys are required**

Comment: i have no internet connection in my Ubuntu m/c, can i offline download and install ipheth-utils, if yes is there any dependency list for that

Comment: @dsharma: Use Keryx Offline Package Manager: http://keryxproject.org/