# How to get an RPi2 running Kali to tether to an iPhone 5S?

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, kali-linux, iphone

I’ve got [Offensive Security’s version of Kali Linux](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-arm-image-download/) running on a Raspberry Pi 2 and I’m trying to tether it to an un-jailbroken AT&T iPhone 5S. From my research it looks like I need to install [ipheth - iPhone USB Ethernet Driver for Linux](https://github.com/dgiagio/ipheth) thus I tried echox's answer on [How to use iphone internet tethering via USB with Ubuntu 10.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4281/how-to-use-iphone-internet-tethering-via-usb-with-ubuntu-10-04) (it's the second answer) but no joy ... so, has anyone managed to get an RPi2 running Kali to tether to an iPhone 5S and, if so, how?